# SQL:: Foreign key :: связь с несколькими таблицами

Tags: sql

Добрый день!

Очень хочется связать ключом поле одной таблицы, сразу с несколькими в зависимости от условия в другом поле.

Пример:

таблица А (servicesA), содержит в себе:

> id, name, order_date

таблица Б (servicesB), содержит в себе:

> id, type, start_date

таблица связи содержит в себе:

> uid, service_type, service_id

Где, `service_id` равен `id` из таблицы `servicesA` или `servicesB`, а `service_type` содержит системные имена сервисов. Можно ли добиться того, что бы в зависимости от значения `service_type` поле `service_id` связывалось бы ключом с той или иной таблицы?

Comment: Такое можно сделать только триггерами. обычными foreign key так нельзя. с другой стороны, такая возможность обычно и не требуется, явно напрашивается объединение таблиц servicesA и B в одну общую таблицу

Comment: @Mike увы, объединить A и B в одну таблицу нельзя - там около 20 полей в каждой, и единственное поле которое есть и там и там - `id`. Да и таких А и В - восемь штук (

Comment: А вы их просто так назвали очень похоже ? Судя по названию они явно одна сущность. Да, может у разных услуг разный набор атрибутов, но если с ними можно работать независимо от их типа (как вы это сейчас пытаетесь сделать), то напрашивается одна общая таблица. Либо в ней должно быть много колонок которые у данных экземпляров NULL, либо дополнительные атрибуты должны быть в как сейчас в разных таблицах, но все общие атрибуты можно собрать в одну таблицу, где как минимум будет id и service_type, а в тех 8 таблицах id не собственные, а ссылающиеся на общую таблицу

Comment: @Mike похоже назвал просто так - так то имена таблиц по названию сервисов. Единственное как с ними можно работать в сумме - это привязывать к ним клиентов, заказавших услугу - для чего собственно говоря и используется таблица сравнения. Делать из них общую таблицу, ну это - тот еще гемор, там будет около 120 различных полей, легче все же разбить немного.А вторая Ваша идея опять же упирается в то, что нужно будет либо держать все в одной огромной таблице, либо все так же пытаться связать одну колонку с разными таблицами.

Comment: Ну названия тут не причем на самом деле :) Вопрос в их сути. Модель БД по хорошему должна отражать объекты так, как они выглядят в жизни. Есть сервисы, оказываемые пользователю. Сервис тут явно самостоятельная сущность. поэтому напрашивается таблица "сервисы" где они все. Сервисы оказываются разных видов, нужны дополнительные таблицы для хранения - ок. Заметьте, эти таблицы, индивидуальности, ссылаются на одну общую таблицу, а не наоборот. Поэтому ситуации, что надо сослаться на несколько таблиц нет.

Comment: @Mike ну т.е. в целом - такой ключ как я хочу, т.е. ключ с доп.условием - прописать нельзя?
Так то, оно и без него вполне себе резво ползает, просто возникла мысль, что если можно - вероятно что-нибудь стало бы проще)

Comment: Ключи нужны только для того, что бы поддерживать целостность БД, что бы нельзя было просто так удалить сервис, на который имеются ссылки, например. На скорость работы ключи сами по себе не влияют, никак. Однако когда вы создаете ключ, БД для обеспечения его работы строит индекс, который все ускоряет. Но индекс то можно построить и руками, без всяких ключей, если есть проблемы с производительностью